# Why does "dynamic" require language-specific runtime components?

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic

Microsoft.CSharp is required to use `dynamic` feature.
I understand there are binders, evaluators and helpers in the assembly.
But why it has to be language-specific?
Why Microsoft.CSharp and not Microsoft.Dynamic or System.Dynamic?

Please, explain.
Let's say we have `d.x` where `d` is `dynamic`.
C# compiler
1. applies C# language rules
2. gets "property or field access"
3. emits (figurally) Binder.GetPropertyOrField(d, "x")
Now, being asked to reference Microsoft.CSharp may make one think that language-agnostic binder can't handle this case, and C#-only *something* got its way through compilation and requires special library.
Compiler had a bad day?

Comment: Because it's the C#-specific runtime compiler parts that help compile against [System.Dynamic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic(v=vs.110).aspx), basically.

Comment: @CodeCaster Sure, sure. But why is something left "uncompiled" to require language-specific runtime compiler parts? Do you have an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To your first question, it is language-specific because it needs to be.

In C# you call a method with too many arguments and you get an error. In Javascript, the extra arguments are simply ignored. In C# you access a member that doesn't exist and get an error, while in Javascript you get `undefined`. Even if you discovered all these varying feature sets and put it all into System.Core, the next language fad of the month is sure to have some super neat feature that it wouldn't support. It's better to be flexible.

There *is* common code in .NET core, under the System.Dynamic and System.Runtime.CompilerServices namespaces. It just can't all be common.

And as for your second question, the need for the "special C# library" could of course be removed by transforming these language-specific behaviors inline, but why? That will needlessly bloat your IL code size. It is the same reasoning for you not writing your own `Int32.Parse` every time you need to read in a number.

Comment: Thank you, I think I got your point. Programs may be complex enough to benefit much from extracting behaviors into separate assembly. And there is no reason not to host it within framework (except portability and backwards compatibility issues).

Answer (score 2):

One reason I can think of - Visual Basic.NET has had [late binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0tcf61s1.aspx) in it from day one, primarily oriented around how it interoperates with COM `IDispatch` interfaces - so if they wanted a language agnostic binder, they'd have had to adopt the Visual Basic rules - which includes that member lookup only works with `Public` members.

Apparently, the C# designers didn't want to be so strict. You can call this class' `DoStuff` method from C# via a dynamic reference:

```
public class Class1
{
    internal void DoStuff()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello");
    }
}
```

Whereas attempting to call the same via Visual Basic's `Object` results in a `MissingMemberException` at runtime.

So because the C# designers weren't the first to arrive at the late-binding party, they could either follow Visual Basic's lead or they could say "each language will have its own rules" - they went with the latter.

Comment: Having own rules is understandable, however, it does not instantly and automatically leads us (me, at least) to another assembly. Also, I got an impression reading your answer, that VB-specific binder (the only at some point) resides within core libraries. Is that so?